# Placeholder asterisk not showing in FF 33.1

Tags: css, html

I found this snippet of code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" class="email"/>

::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
   content: '*';
}

:-moz-placeholder:after { /* Firefox 18- */
   content: '*'; 
}

::-moz-placeholder:after {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   content: '*';
}

:-ms-input-placeholder:after {  
   content: '*';
}
```

Although it says FF 19+, when tested on FF 33.1 (my current version) the asterisk is not displayed.

I am validating a form and I would need to have an asterisk in all the required inputs.

Thanks

Comment: I found this solution but it looks very bad :( http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/bvJ43/